# tikz-timing missing clock arrow

Tags: tikz-timing

I'am drawing a simple serial Protocol where the first n clock pulses are represented by one 'dotted' clock Pulse. But this one has no rising arrow, how could one fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage[active, tightpage, psfixbb]{preview}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikztiminglibrary{clockarrows, nicetabs}

\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    scale = 1.5,
    timing/.cd,
    dslope = 0.1,
    c/rising arrows,
    c/arrow pos = 0.7,
    c/arrow tip = stealth'
    ]
    Foo & H L D ;[dotted] 2D; D{} D ;[dotted] 2D; D L\\
    Bar & 1.5H 1.5L ;[dotted] 2{C}; 2{C} ;[dotted] 2{C}; 2{C}\\
  \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Image]

In the result you can see that the first rising arrow is missing at the **1.5L ;[dotted] 2{C}** transition. Later at the signal the **2{C} ;[dotted] 2{C}** provides an arrow as expected.

Causes the 'low' to 'clock' switching this effect?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE works fine in xelatex, probably, tikz-timing patched this behavior. but if you (for some reason) don't want to update your package - there's a workaround - using `c` signal as a last `l` like this:

```latex
Bar & 1.5H Ll [c];[dotted] 2{C}; 2{C} ;[dotted] 2{C}; 2{C}
```

which makes clk signal to begin from other clk signal, but not from logic one.

[image: nice MWE]